# Using env in VSCode's launch.json to expand placeholders in Spring Boot's application properties

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code, gradle

I have a Gradle and Spring Boot project. In the `application.properties` file I have properties like `my.prop=${my-env:}`. Setting a system wide environment variable `my-env` works as expected, but I want to set the environment variables when I launch the application, like you can do in the Run Configurations in IntelliJ. I found the `env` and `envFile` properties for `launch.json`:

```
...
"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
...
```

or

```
...
"env": {
   "my-env":"some value",
   ...
}
...
```

Neither does anything for me. Particularly the `envFile` method doesn't even tell me when there is no file at `${workspaceFolder}/.env`.

A method using a separate file would be best for me, in order to exclude these variables from version control.

**Update**: I start the application using the Gradle VSCode plugin. When I use the built-in "Start Debugging" I see

> ... cmd /C "set "my-env=some value" ...

in the first line of the terminal output. The variables of the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes are empty strings though.

Comment: I got it to work. Unfortunately I can't say what exactly was the problem. The solution involved opening the main gradle project in VSCode instead a subdirectory (and then using the working launch.json with the subdir) and restarting VSCode several times.